# Would it be possible to add a search function in my asked questions?

Tags: feature-request, search, profile-page

Would it be possible to add a search function in my asked questions? It takes considerable amount of time if a user asked a few questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in the regular search box (see the [search options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search))

```
user:1234 query
```

For example this is a search for [some of my stuff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22459+formatting+sandbox)

```
user:22459 formatting sandbox
```

You can also use the shorthand for your own questions/answers by replacing the ID with `me`, à la:

```
user:me feet
```

Comment: ah cool, would be nice to have some UI on the profile page though

Comment: click the search box and search for an empty value. Then you'll get an FAQ.