# Is it possible to add a search-box for voted questions/posts?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, voting, search

I'm using Stack Exchange to learn new things and a little bit like a wiki... And from time to time I come across new topics with many questions and answers. I upvote them because they are really good and/or I thought about a similar question.

It would be nice to easily find them again after some time, when facing a problem which is related and not have to go through all (in my personal point of view low-quality or not appropriate) questions/answers again. I know I can mark questions as favorites, but marking them all will result in too many favorites which going through all the time is also tedious.

I'm thinking about a **(live-)search/filter** at the **votes-section beside the other filters**. If not at all, it would also be an improvement for the answers-, questions- and favorites-sections. *Additional, I think this would be easier to handle for new (non-tech) users than a advanced search-syntax.*

[image: Suggestion]

The same problem occurs for example in the flagging history:
For flagging recurring questions as duplicates I use the same high-voted question from time to time. - I can't mark them all as favorite to easily find them and using the browser-integrated search for >1000 flags and therefore >25 sites isn't really applicable.

---

Based on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19627/339119 as an alternative an [additional "advanced search key"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206804/find-posts-i-upvoted) like `voted:byme`, maybe also `upvoted:byme` and `downvoted:byme` would be a little bit more inconvenient option (whereby *`:byme`* may be unnecessary because of the "anonymous votes"-policy).

Comment: You're talking about answers that you have upvoted right? Because your screenshot is on the tab for *your answers* (and you can already search your own questions/answers/favourites using the regular search).

Comment: yes (i took answers for the screenshot because they are empty)... the "idea" is coming from the posts i've upvoted, but as said it would make sense at more sections and be easier to handle for new (non-tech) users.